# magento connections to two databases

Tags: php, magento

I have a problem in magento. i want to connect two databases with magento.one database will be the main database and the other will be for stores. I dont know how to do it.By this time my connection is in the file app/etc/local.xml.....my local.xml is follows
please help
    
        
            
                
            
            
               
           
            false
           
            
                
            
            
                
                    
                    
                    
                    
                    [mysql4]]>
                    
                    
                    1

Comment: http://blog.decryptweb.com/connect-database-magento/ try this link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be a more elegant solution that what I've implemented, but my method works. I did this for an osCommerce import/export module.

---

/httpdocs/app/etc/config.xml

```
        <!-- osCommerce db/read/write -->
        <oscommercedb>
            <connection>
                <host>localhost</host>
                <username>root</username>
                <password>pass</password>
                <dbname>oscommerce_database_name</dbname>
                <model>mysql4</model>
                <initstatements>SET NAMES utf8</initstatements>
                <type>pdo_mysql</type>
                <active>1</active>
            </connection>
        </oscommercedb>
        <oscommercedb_write>
            <connection>
                <use>oscommercedb</use>
            </connection>
        </oscommercedb_write>
        <oscommercedb_read>
            <connection>
                <use>oscommercedb</use>
            </connection>
        </oscommercedb_read>
        <!-- end osCommerce db -->
```

---

This gives you the ability to call `oscommercedb` within your models. The above code goes within the `<resources>` block.

Let's take a look at a model now.

---

/httpdocs/app/code/local/Company/Extension/Model/OsCustomers.php

```
class Company_Extension_Model_OsCustomers extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{

protected $_name = 'customers'; // name of the table

/**
 * Returns rowset of tables for customers
 *
 * @return Zend_Db_Table_Rowset
 */
public function getAllOscommerceCustomers()
{
    $read = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('oscommercedb');

    $stmt = $read->select();

    $stmt->from(array('c' => 'customers'))
         ->join(array('a' => 'address_book'), 'a.address_book_id = c.customers_default_address_id')
         ->joinLeft('zones', 'zones.zone_id = a.entry_zone_id')
         ->join('countries','a.entry_country_id = countries.countries_id', array('countries_iso_code_2'));

    return $read->fetchAll($stmt);
}
```

---

If you run into a specific problem let me know.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help.I was able to do it very easily with your code.